# Is there any way to find a function h(i) such that the sum of h(i) is the domain of this function?

Tags: functions

I want to find a continuous function h(i), which domain is from 1 to t. And the sum of all values of h(i) is equal to t - 1

Is there any way to find a such function?

Comment: Let $t = 1$ and $h(1) = 1$.

Comment: Do you mean the domain to be an interval $[1,t]$?  And if so, what then does the "sum of all values" mean?

Comment: sum of all values is like:  h(1) + h(1.0000001)+ ... + h(t).

Answer (score 0):

A continuous function doesn't have a sum as you have described.

Instead it has an integral.

You need $\int _1 ^t h(x)dx=t-1$

If $H(x)$ is the antiderivative of $h(x)$, then $H(t)-H(1)=t-1$

An obvious solution is to set $H(x)=x+c$. Then $H(t)-H(1)=(t+c)-(1+c)=t-1$ as required.

$h(x)=\frac{dH}{dx}=1$

Comment: This is not correct. If h(x) = 1, I will add infinite 1s together because h is a continuous function and there is infinite x i can choose between 1 and t.

Comment: That's why you can't use a sum for a continuous function: you should be using an integral. There is no meaning to a 'sum of a continuous function.'